# How can I retrieve this data from mongodb into node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backend

```
db.location.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "city_name" : "Delhi", "city" : 1, "country_name" : "India" }
{ "_id" : 3, "city_name" : "Pune", "city" : 3, "country_name" : "India" }
{ "_id" : 2, "city_name" : "Mumbai", "city" : 2, "country_name" : "India" }
{ "_id" : 4, "city_name" : "Chandigarh", "city" : 4, "country_name" : "India" }
{ "_id" : 5, "city_name" : "Goa", "city" : 5, "country_name" : "India" }
{ "_id" : 6, "city_name" : "Manali", "city" : 6, "country_name" : "India" }
```

This is the `app.js` file... I tried using this but it's not working... I'm getting this error `{"name":"MongoError"}`

```js
var dbo = db.db("mydb");
dbo.collection('location').find({}).toArray(function (err, result) 
{
    if (err) {
              return res.send(err);
              } else 
              {
                return res.send(JSON.stringify(result))
                }
               })
```

Comment: Maybe try something like res.json(result)

Comment: @danibrum it's still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code.

```
dbo.collection('location').find({
  ^
```

should be

```
db.collection('location').find({
```

You had an extra 'o'.

Comment: i've edited my code can you tell me what's the error now? i'm inserting that data which i mentioned above and then i'm trying to retrieve it with this code..